# Small UIImage view in custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, custom-cell

I have UICollectionViewCell

```
#import "DBPhotoCollectionViewCell.h"
#define IMAGEVIEW_BORDER_LENGTH 5
    @implementation DBPhotoCollectionViewCell
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

/* Need to implement the initWithCoder method since this class will be created from the storyboard */
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self){
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

/* Create the UIImageView and add it to the cell's contentView in code. */
-(void)setup
{
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, IMAGEVIEW_BORDER_LENGTH, IMAGEVIEW_BORDER_LENGTH)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
}


@end
```

And call this Cell from CollectionViewController class

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photo Cell";

    DBPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Astronaut.jpg"];
    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}
```

But I have one problem when I start my application my picture is showed with small size. What I missed?

http://screencast.com/t/ia8tE05P6yc
http://screencast.com/t/33N4AhT7

Comment: What does self.bounds return? I think it will be the default cell size (50 x 50) when you check this in an init method.

Comment: I manualy set cell size in main.storyboard 155 x 155. I think I missed to set  Cell size in Collection View settings too. I have opened storyboard as Source Code and found place where should be 155 x 155 too.

Comment: <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="Photo Cell" id="Plr-w7-PFO" customClass="TWPhotoCollectionViewCell">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="155" height="155"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cell.imageView, imageView object is not same as which you have added on cell of Interface Builder. UICollectionViewCell has default size UIImageView which are accessing, you can access your customView imageView in cellForIndexPath method of collectionView by linking imageView of subClass DBPhotoCollectionViewCell in interface builder you don't need to add  [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView]; in setup method.

Second approach would be assign tag value to imageView when you adding to cell contentView

```
/* Create the UIImageView and add it to the cell's contentView in code. */
-(void)setup
{
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, IMAGEVIEW_BORDER_LENGTH, IMAGEVIEW_BORDER_LENGTH)];
self.imageView.tag=1;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
}

//And access imagView in cellForIndexPath

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photo Cell";

    DBPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   UIImageView *imageView=[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Astronaut.jpg"];
    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't. My reputation is to low. ;(